# Cypress, randomly, can't find elements with .contains('etc')

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a table with 5 elements and I'm clicking an element found by .contains(). Sometimes, is working and everything is ok but sometimes is saying that can't find element in dom. After test restart, is working.

Never happened this type of fails with Selenium and I don't understand why is failing randomly on Cypress.

```js
editTitle(title) {
  cy.get(table).within(() => {
    cy.get(elms.elmTitle)
      .contains(title)
      .siblings(elms.elmActions)
      .children(elms.elmActionEdit)
      .click()
    }
  )
}
```

Any explanation? What am I missing?

I'm using latest version but happened with previously.
Thank you!

Comment: Where is `elms` defined? Are you sure the table contents (including the button) are fully rendered before you click them? You could try adding a `.should('be.visible')` before the click. This retries the assertion until it times out (by default I think it's 4 seconds)

Comment: Thank you for answer! Yes, everything is declared as constants outside the class (for a better organisation). 

I have tried with .should('exist') but I have same behavior, randomly. Everything is rendered, because the cy.get(table) is waiting for the requests to be finished and everything is loaded.

Comment: `should('exist')` will not fail if the element is detached from the DOM (or hidden by CSS), while `should(be.visible')` will.

Comment: Could you share your HTML as well?